# Regex for valid java identifier

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regex for a valid java identifier name: I have tried this:

```
([a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z\d_$]*)
```

but it is accepting spaces also. However, I didn't allowed space to be considered as a match.

Any idea?

Comment: You seem to use it to validate an entire string, so your issue is missing anchors.

Comment: Although most Java identifiers use Ascii, all UTF-8 characters are allowed, so it's better to use \p{L} instead of a-zA-Z.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the `start` and `end` markers to enforce that the *entire* string matches the regex. Otherwise, it passes if any part of the string matches.

`^([a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z\d_$]*)$`